# Do two INNER JOIN's with DJANGO and retrieve variable(s)

Tags: python, sql, database, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a attribute of a django model, following the Foreign Keys relations between 3 tables.
My SQL query is exactly this:

```
select
     DATABASE.TABLE1.id, DATABASE.TABLE3.name
from
    DATABASE.TABLE1
        Inner Join
    DATABASE.TABLE2 ON DATABASE.TABLE2.TABLE1_id = DATABASE.TABLE1.id
        Inner Join
    DATABASE.TABLE3 ON DATABASE.TABLE2.TABLE3_id = DATABASE.TABLE3.id
```

How do I do this query using django? I also want to do this in only one queryset. Is it possible?

Thanks!

P.S.- **TABLE2** have the Foreign Keys to the **TABLE1** and **TABLE3**.

**EDIT 1** - Models.py

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'App'
        db_table = 'Table1'

class Table2(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(table1 , db_column='TABLE1 _ID')
    table2 = models.ForeignKey(table2, db_column='TABLE2_ID')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'App'
        db_table = 'Table2'

class Table3(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'App'
        db_table = 'Table3'
```

I want that to get the variables TABLE1.id and TABLE3.name.

Comment: Please show the models, and the exact expected result.

Comment: Is it more understandable now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that there isn't a "the" Table3.name, because you have what is effectively a many-to-many relationship. For each instance of Table1, you have many Table3 instances, and vice versa.

However, it is fairly simple to get *all* the Table3.name values for a single Table1 instance. 
The easiest way would be to add an explicit declaration for the many-to-many relationship - note that this is a logical field only, and does not require any schema changes.

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    ...
    table3s = models.ManyToManyField('Table3', through='Table2')
```

now you can do:

```
my_table_1.table3s.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

(I'm assuming your declaration of Table2 is supposed to have a FK to Table3, not back to itself, and that this is simply a mistake in the example.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But now suppose that Table1 was actually the django built-in User model (`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`). If I can't access the model declaration how to I do it?

Comment: You can put the M2M field on either side of the relationship, so put it on Table3 and use the reverse relationship accessor: `my_user.table3_set.values_list(...)`.